# Docker containers gone after Gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I installed a Gitlab runner with the docker executor on my Raspberry Pi. In my Gitlab repository I have a docker-compose.yaml file which should run 2 containers, 1 for the application and 1 for the database. It works on my laptop Then I built a simple pipeline with 2 stages test and deploy. This is my deploy stage:

```
deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker compose down
    - docker compose build
    - docker compose up -d
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

In the pipeline logs I can see that network, volumes and containers get created and the containers are started. It then says

```
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:03
Job succeeded
```

When I ssh into the my raspi and do `docker ps -a` none of the containers are displayed. It is as if nothing has happened.

I compared my setup to the one in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RV0845KmsNI&t=352s and my pipeline looks similar. The only difference I can figure out is that in the video a shell executor is used for the Gitlab runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences between using the docker and the shell executor. When you use docker the docker-compose will start your application+db inside the container created to run the job and when the job finishes this container will be stopped by the GitLab runner as well as your application+db inside it. On the other hand, when using the shell executor all the commands of the job are executed directly in the system's shell, so when the job execution has finished the containers of your application+db should remain running in the system. One of the advantages of using the docker executor is precisely that it isolates the job execution inside a docker container, and when it finishes the job container is stopped and the system where the GitLab runner is running is not affected at all (this may change if you have configured the runner to run docker as root).

So my suggested solution is to change the executor to shell (you have to handle security issues).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Putting the docker stuff in the before_script-section unfortunately didn't make a difference. Containers were started in the pipeline but once the pipeline was over, they were gone. I removed my gitlab-runner and installed a new one with a shell executor. Now it's working. I would like to accept your answer if you remove the part with the before_script. :)

Comment: Glad to help @Ole. Thanks for the comment. I agree and have edited the post.

Comment: I think the docker container is removed as well, as a result of being stopped. IOW, there is no way to access the container with docker-exec when the pipeline is finished. Please correct me if I'm wrong.